# Python: "unexpected end of regular expression" during re.compile, empty brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

To summarize i have `re.compile` statement like so:

```
markers = ['x'] # some list
re.compile(r" *[{}].*(?=\n|$)".format('\\'.join([''] + markers)))
```

For most cases it works fine **unless `markers` is empty** and RegEx pattern looks like so:

```
pattern = ' *[].*(?=\\n|$)'
```

Why does it have problem with **empty character set**? What is the workaround to make it work for empty `markers` list?

### SOLUTION

Credits for: [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters), [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) and [Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan).

To summarize:

- **empty character set** doesn't exist in RegEx. `[]` is parsed like `[a` so interpreter expects closing `]` and that causes error,
- checking for empty `markers` must be done before compiling this pattern, to avoid invalid empty brackets `[]`,
- `.*(?=\n|$)` has redundant `(?=\n|$)` and can be simplified to `.*`,
- to escape special characters efficiently inside brackets `[]` it it's better to use `re.escape()`.

Adding thigs up the solution for my problem is:

```
if markers:
    re.compile(r" *[{}].*".format(re.escape(''.join(markers))))
else:
    # something
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty character class, so `[]` is invalid. Test for an empty markers list and compile a simpler expression?

Comment: Also, `(?=\n|$)` is redundant.

Comment: Well, the current code throws an exception, as `\x` is not a valid pattern (there must be 2 digits after it). You cannot escape just any character you want like that.

Comment: So with `markers`  empty, you are basically looking for some whitespace. Another note: just use `re.escape()` rather than prepend everything manually with ``\``.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Not invalid as such, just incomplete. `re.compile(r"[]]").sub("found", "]")`. Specifically, there are two ways to escape the closing bracket when in a character class: by prepending backslash, or by making sure it is the first character in the character class. So when you write `[]`, it's just like writing `[a` - regexp still wants you to close the bracket.

Comment: @Amadan: just a different way of putting it; there is no empty character class.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, I agree, just wanted to clarify for OP what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if the markers list is not empty *at the very beginning*, then, only escape the characters that must be escaped in the character class: `^`, `\`, `]`, `[`, `-`.

Note that if the markers list is empty, the pattern becomes  `*.*`, basically accepting *any line*. You can match it with `"^.*$"`.

Here is my suggestion:

```
import re
markers = ['x', ']', '[', '-', '^', '\\'] # some list
global p
#markers = [] # some list
if markers:
    escaped = [re.sub(r"[][^\\-]", r"\\\g<0>", x) for x in markers]
    pat = r" *[{}].*".format("".join(escaped))
    p = re.compile(pat)
else:
    p = re.compile("^.*$")

print(p.pattern)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JxNBa0)

Also,  the `.*(?=\n|$)` can be actually reduced to `.*` since `.` matches any character but a newline (it also can match a CR symbol) and `.*` will always match all chars up to the `\n` or end of string.